# My pygame player sprite is not moving and/or updating

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I am trying to build a simple "flappy bird" like game. I am trying to sort all the code into classes and methods. How do I fix this problem? Is it the code not working because of calling some method too early or is it because there's something missing? I would really love it if someone would try to explain to me.

sprites.py:

```
import pygame


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = (700 / 2)
        self.movex = 0
        self.movey = 0

    def control(self, x, y):
        self.movex += x
        self.movey += y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.movex
        self.rect.y += self.movey

    def animate(self):
        pass


class Obstacle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
```

main.py:

```
from sprites import *
import pygame

WIDTH = 700
HEIGHT = 700


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.score = 0
        self.running = True

    def new(self):
        pass

    def events(self):
        self.game_on = True
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.game_on = False
                self.running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.croc.control(0, -20)

    def update(self):
        self.croc = Player()
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_sprites.add(self.croc)
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()


game = Game()

while game.running:
    game.clock.tick(60)
    game.new()
    game.events()
    game.update()
    game.draw()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes. The `Player` object is recreated in every frame. Create the player in the constructor of `Game` rather than in the method `update`:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # [...]

        self.croc = Player()                     # <--- ADD
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group() # <--- ADD
        self.all_sprites.add(self.croc)          # <--- ADD

    def update(self):
        # self.croc = Player()                     # <--- DELETE
        # self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group() # <--- DELETE
        # self.all_sprites.add(self.croc)          # <--- DELETE
        self.all_sprites.update()
```

There is a type in the event loop. You've to get the key from the `.key` attribute rather than the `.type` attriburte:

<s>`if event.type == pygame.K_UP:`</s>

```py
if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
```

---

Complete code:

```py
import pygame

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = (700 / 2)
        self.movex = 0
        self.movey = 0

    def control(self, x, y):
        self.movex += x
        self.movey += y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.movex
        self.rect.y += self.movey

    def animate(self):
        pass


class Obstacle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height


WIDTH = 700
HEIGHT = 700

class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.score = 0
        self.running = True
        self.croc = Player()
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_sprites.add(self.croc)

    def new(self):
        pass

    def events(self):
        self.game_on = True
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.game_on = False
                self.running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.croc.control(0, -20)

    def update(self):
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()


game = Game()

while game.running:
    game.clock.tick(60)
    game.new()
    game.events()
    game.update()
    game.draw()
```

Comment: `self.all_sprites` should also not be being reinitialized each call to `game.update()` either.  The setup of `self.all_sprites` should be moved into the Game constructor as well. After moving that the only thing left in `game.update()` would be the call to `self.all_sprites.update()`.

Comment: @GlennMackintosh You are absolutely right, I overlooked that. Thanks